# Работа с рядами данных (Series)

Tags: delphi

У меня хранятся данные в массиве FDub5.Chart1.Series
Я так добавлял в него точки для графика

```
 FDub5.Chart1.Series[0].AddXY(XXiz,0);
 FDub5.Chart1.Series[1].AddXY(XXiz,0);

 FDub5.Chart1.Series[0].AddXY(Xiz,0);
 FDub5.Chart1.Series[1].AddXY(Xiz,0);

 FDub5.Chart1.Series[0].AddXY(aX[jX]*1000,Yizmp[jX,jY]);
 FDub5.Chart1.Series[1].AddXY(aX[jX]*1000,-Yizmp[jX,jY]);
 FDub5.Chart1.Series[4].AddXY(aX[1],Yizmp[jX,jY]*(1.5));
 FDub5.Chart1.Series[5].AddXY(aX[1],-Yizmp[jX,jY]*(1.5));
```

там 6 рядов данных:

```
 FDub5.Chart1.Series[0].Clear;//Сброс
 FDub5.Chart1.Series[1].Clear;//Сброс
 FDub5.Chart1.Series[2].Clear;//Сброс
 FDub5.Chart1.Series[3].Clear;//Сброс
 FDub5.Chart1.Series[4].Clear;//Сброс
 FDub5.Chart1.Series[5].Clear;//Сброс
```

как мне вывести данные, которые хранятся в Series и как изменить эти данные? А потом вывести эти данные, на другом графике?

Comment: Для доступа к данным можно воспользоваться методами `Series.XValues.Value[0]`  `Series.YValues.Value[0]`. Но как по мне лучше хранить данные в массиве, а потом их "переиспользовать".

Comment: Да лучше хранить в массиве, но мне надо изменить эти данные. Эти точки строят Изолинию в метрах, а мне надо перевести эти метры в географические координаты, относительно введёно координаты  и добавить новый график.